# indexof dropdown item in c sharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want Index of drop down list item. I have item in string variable and passing in IndexOf method but it gives me error. I did it as follows.

```
string val = "abc";
int index1 = ddl2.Items.IndexOf(val);
```

It gives as invalid argument.
Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: Because `DropDownList.Items` is a collection of `ListItem` items, not strings.

Comment: If values of your `ddl2` are unique, then you could do something like this `ddl2.Items.Select(li => li.Text).ToList().IndexOf(val)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this(only if your values are unique)

```
string val = "abc";
int index1 = ddl2.Items.IndexOf(ddl2.Items.FindByValue(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

It gets listItem type the indexOf method and not string.
Maybe you want to try something like:

```
var l1 =new ListItem("text_1", "abc"); //abc the value
int index1 = ddl.Items.IndexOf(l1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use directly this

```
string val = "abc";
int index1 = ddl2.Items.IndexOf(ddl2.Items.FindByText(val));
```

because the value you are looking for is a string

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.findbytext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for documentation

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to use `SelectedIndex` property of dropdownlist

```
Int index=ddl.SelectedIndex
```